# Clone existing sharepoint 2013 server and join to same farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-farm

i have one staging SharePoint 2013 + Project server 2013 server installed and there is two web applications working on it .
I want to clone this server in order to create another webfront end server instead of creating new server.

Here if i clone existing sharepoint 2013 server sharepoint and service applications and webapplication should be work fine or not?
and most important the clone server i want to join to same farm

Comment: I don't think that it is a good idea. I've tried to clone whole farm once but it did not work well and then I removed all cloned servers and created new farm with fresh install. Cloning only one server, I guess, doesn't cause such problems but I would try to create a new server. Instead off trying to solve cloned server problems, create a new server.

Comment: 1+ to what @newbie said. Cloning is not a good idea, you should create a new server, apply the same patches and then join the server to the farm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloning of SharePoint is not supported, You may able to get it work but it will throw a lot unknown errors after it whcih will be pain.

Keep in mind, cloning after running config wizard is not gonna work, as it put hard reference in config DB. when you add the clone server in the same farm will cause stability issue.

read here for cloning related work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379310/whats-the-best-strategy-to-add-wfe-server-to-a-sharepoint-farm-in-virtualised-e